How can an Investigator get critical specialization effects on unarmed attacks?
Investigators don't seem to get crit effects on level 5 like most martials. With various Weapon Familiarity feats you can get it for weapons, but it does not work even for ancestral attacks.
I found the Predator's Claw talisman, but it takes up the talisman slot, which I want to use with a Fear Gem.
The archetype is Martial Artist, if it matters.
Is there a way?

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but Orc's Bloody Blows essentially gives you an alternate crit spec for unarmed attacks.

@ESCE, 1d4 persistent damage on level 5 is not really comparable to slowed 1. Even if the latter allows a save

Brawling Focus
Martial Artist can take Brawling Focus at level 4, which offers critical specialization for all unarmed attacks.

You know how to make the most of your attacks when fighting hand-to-hand. You gain access to the critical specialization effects of unarmed strikes in the brawling group and weapons in the brawling group. If you have Monastic Weaponry, you also gain the critical specialization effects of all monk weapons in which you are trained.


How have I missed that?
